# validate japanese language same meaning in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I have a validated name of shools like

```
'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:shools,name'
```

my record in database

> はのい

my input

> ハノイ

but it gives me the error, I think because they have the same meaning

> "The name has already been taken."

but I want it to pass validation, someone can help me?

Comment: `ハノイ` and `はのい` is different string, so it should pass validation. What  is the DB you used? I tried on Postgres and it can be inserted.

Comment: I used mysql:5.7 and MySQL is required for this project

Comment: I can't speak Japanese but they certainly seem to be the [same symbols](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AE%E3%81%84%0D%0A%E3%83%8F%E3%83%8E%E3%82%A4), just in different scripts. Do you have Japanese collation implemented somewhere in your stack? And, would it be okay to allow both as different names? It feels like having both `Harvard` and `harvard`.

Comment: In particular, I presume that Laravel merely launches a select query against MySQL. You need to verify the table collation.